# Can I force notify-send to appear on a different monitor?

Tags: rhel, kde, notifications

I am using notify-send to present occasional information to my users.
However, in a two-monitor setup, notify-send always maps the window in the lower-right corner of the right monitor.

The users would like the popup moved to the lower-right corner of the left monitor.

notify-send doesn't appear to allow the -geometry command-line argument, and Control Center -> Window-Specific Settings can't seem to identify the window class automatically.

Is there a way to force notify-send to appear at a specific location, or is there a suitable alternative that comes with RHEL5?

Comment: Please add a tag (or text) specifying your windowing system.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Sorry, I should have said this is KDE.

Answer (score 2):

You might try changing the display variable slightly:

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 notify-send [options] "summary" "body"
```

Usually, your desktop screens are :0, and the main is :0.0, second is :0.1, and so forth.

If I remember correctly, this should put it on the other screen.

you might need to have a wrapper script or such to change the value of DISPLAY when executing the notify-send application.  As long as its in the path before the real one, it'll work nicely without anyone noticing really.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing DISPLAY does not affect notify-send on my system.  On what system did you see this work?

Comment: It's been a while, I'll see what I can pull together to figure out what works.

Comment: Does not work on Archlinux.